# Configurar N níveis no htaccess

Tags: php, htaccess

No site temos a área de produtos onde poderá existir N níveis e subníveis de categorias.
Atualmente o htaccess está configurado para aceitar 2 níveis:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_-]+)/produtos/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*) index.php?area=produtos&lang=$1&n1=$2&n2=$3&n3=$4 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_-]+)/produtos/([^/]*)/([^/]*) index.php?area=produtos&lang=$1&n1=$2&n2=$3 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_-]+)/produtos/([^/]*) index.php?area=produtos&lang=$1&n1=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

A URL fica da seguinte forma:

> localhost/pt/produtos/1-sapatos/5-couro/15-sapatoXPTO
>   localhost/pt/produtos/1-sapatos/5-couro
>   localhost/pt/produtos/1-sapatos

Funciona perfeitamente para 2 níveis de categorias, porém quero eliminar essa limitação e permitir N níveis de categorias.

Como faço para passar para o index.php o que está a frente do "produtos/" independentemente da quantidade de níveis?

Comment: A regra usada e o exemplo não batem. Onde entra a `lang` no exemplo citado?

Comment: @PapaCharlie editei o exemplo, me esqueci de adicionar o idioma, no exemplo adicionei o "pt".

Comment: O que está na frente de *produtos*, no caso é o idioma, representado por `$1`, e você já está passando ele com `lang=$1`. Pode explicar melhor o que deseja fazer?

Comment: @PapaCharlie não leve em consideração o idioma (serve apenas para passar o idioma selecionado para o PHP através do parâmetro lang), o problema são os níveis de categorias conforme explicado acima, considere apenas o que está a frente da barra depois de "produtos".

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade você precisará de apenas uma regra no seu arquivo HTACCESS e o resto você fará no seu script PHP, deste modo:

No seu .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^produtos/(.*)\.html?$ index.php?area=produtos&vars=$1 [NC,L]
```

No seu script php:

```
/**
 * Verifica se a variável vars existe
 * se ela existir explode gerando um array
 * caso contrário retorna vazio
 **/
$vars = isset($_REQUEST['vars']) ? explode('/',$_REQUEST['vars']) : '';

// Separando as variáveis
$n0 = isset($vars[0]) ? $vars[0] : '';
$n1 = isset($vars[1]) ? $vars[1] : '';
$n2 = isset($vars[2]) ? $vars[2] : '';
...
$nx = isset($vars[x]) ? $vars[x] : '';
```

Ou para capturar as variáveis de forma mais dinâmica pode-se fazer:

```
foreach ($vars as $k=>$var){
    $n = 'n' . $k;
    $$n = $var;// cria a variável na execução $n0, $n1, $n2, $n3 ... $nx
}
```

Boa sorte!